Python Script Stuck in a For Loop
I have this code that iterates through several links. For each one, it retrieves the HTML response and runs response_html.find('relative-time')
import pandas as pd
import requests_html

def main():
    df_links = pd.read_csv('links2.csv', index_col=0)

    session = requests_html.HTMLSession()

    try:
        for i in range(0, len(df_links.index)):
            url = df_links.iloc[i]['hyperlink']
            print(f"[{i}/{len(df_links.index)}]: {url}", flush=True)
            response = session.get(url)
            status_code = response.status_code
            if status_code == 200:
                response_html = response.html
                dateList = response_html.find('relative-time')
    except Exception as e:
        print("Something went wrong...", flush=True)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()

However, with 15,000 links, the code mysteriously stops halfway through execution and gets stuck in the middle of the for loop. What could be causing this?
I've asked friends to simulate it, and the same thing happened to them.
For testing purposes, the repository with the CSV is available here: https://github.com/carloseduardobanjar/nvd-linked-content-crawler-bug
When I comment out the line dateList = response_html.find('relative-time'), the code runs smoothly until completion. It seems the issue lies within that line.
ps: I know the code may seem nonsensical, but it's just an example to illustrate the problem.

Does it always stop at the same URL?  Can you do that one by itself?

I know the code may seem nonsensical, but it's just an example  I'm guessing the true problem is somewhere in the code you removed in order to make the example.

@TimRoberts yes, it always stop at the same URL, but if I start running from that URL it works.

@JohnGordon I tested the example code and I reproduced the error.

One thing that I noticed is that the response object is being left without closing. The get function from a Session in requests-html returns a requests.Response, which has the close function. Also, the Session supports a close function, maybe you can also try to close and recreate it periodically.

it is worth trying:            with session.get(url, headers=__headers) as response:

Your title intrigued me, because generally Python can't get stuck in a for loop - it will keep iterating until it's done.  You're not really getting stuck in the loop, you just happen to be in the loop when something hangs.

It seems unlikely, but is it possible that in the while loop in __get_response_from_session(), that session.get() is raising an exception that doesn't inherit from Exception, but instead inherits directly from BaseException?  That condition would keep you in that loop indefinitely.

@MiguelAngelo I've attempted to periodically close and reopen the session and use the response close method, but the code still hasn't worked.

You say it always stops on the same URL, but that if you start there it processes that URL. Does it always stop at the same number of inputs, regardless of what the inputs are?

@Chris No, it doesn't always stop at the same number of inputs. If I remove the URL where it usually pauses, it continues to process additional inputs until it encounters another URL that causes it to halt. It appears that the issue is specific to certain URLs rather than a consistent number of inputs.
